# How to access the value of an XML attribute using a String variable? How can this be applied to filtering?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, e4x

Using e4x in flex:

```
var attr : String = "foo";
var xml : XML = 
    <resultSet>
       <node foo="1"/>
    </resultSet>;
```

How can I use the variable "attr" to access

```
xml.node.@foo
```

I thought I could do it with

```
xml.node.@[attr]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I access this attribute by a dynamic value like this?

EDIT:
Both

```
xml.node.@[attr];
```

and

```
xml.node.attribute(attr);
```

work, as Constantiner suggested.

Updates:

Say I have an XMLList in this form:

```
var bar:XML = 
    <resultSet>
         <node>value</node>
    </resultSet>;
```

I want to filter the original xml above by matching "foo" attributes with the "value" from node in bar.

Essentially I want a sublist of the original xml such that

```
xml.node.@foo == bar.value
```

for each xml row in the original value

As Constantiner mentioned, I can filter the original list by the value in foo, but what if I want to filter on multiple values?

Can I do something like:

```
xml.node.(bar.node.contains(attribute(foo)) ? attribute(foo) : null);
```

Or perhaps a cleaner method instead of the null?

Comment: trace(xml.node.@[attr]) returns "1" for me, but it's cleaner (in my opinion) to follow Constantiner's answer and pass the string as a parameter to the attribute method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `xml.node.attribute(attr)`.

Comment: Thanks, turns out both the xml.node.attribute and xml.node.@[attribute] work for a single node, but what about for an e4x filter? like if I want to get an XMLList of just the nodes matching a certain attribute? xml.node.(@[attribute] == value) doesn't seem to work?

Comment: For your XML `xml.node.(attribute("foo") == 1)` works fine. Did you tried something like `xml.node.(attribute(attr) == 1)`?

Comment: Or even `xml.node.(attribute(attr) == value)`?